# Imageformat set in surfaceChanged changes to something else in onPreviewFrame

Tags: android, android-camera

Below attached is the code I am trying. The CamPreview class is being used by the launcher activity. I was able to get preview fine before implementing PreviewCallback. When i try PreviewCallback by implementing onPreviewFrame, i am totally confused how it works internally. Below are the following things that are confusing me. Kindly clarify them.

1) Though i set camera parameters like ImageFormat and Previewsize, they don't seem to persist till the invokation of method onPreviewFrame. For example, the Log.i statements in surfaceChanged method (called immediately atleast once after surfaceCreated as per my understanding) prints the preview size as 1056x864. However, onPreviewFrame reports that the preview size as 1920x1080.

Even the picture format changes from NV21(17 in surfaceChanged) to JPEG(256 in onPreviewFrame).

I have verified and confirmed that the Camera instance passed to onPreviewFrame is same as the member variable `mCamera` declared in CamPreview class.

If i am able to successfully get preview format as NV21 in onPreviewFrame, how do i convert that to ARGB format ? I have tried the methods posted in stackoverflow but the data passed to onPreviewFrame fails due to index out of bounds, which lead to me to check the image formats in the first place. If anyone has tried something similar, pls do let me know what was i missing during the creation that is causing this mess :(.

I have tried to create bitmap by initially creating YuvImage from byte[] passed to onPreviewFrame which gave me green latern images(all green or garbage some times)!

2) You can see other Log.i stmts next to the ones i mentioned in point (1). They print out bits per pixel and bytes per pixel information of the preview in the methods surfaceChanged and onPreviewFrame. They turn out to be 12 and 1 respectively. How is that even possible ? Again, this could be a side effect of what is happening in (1)

```
public class CamPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PreviewCallback {

    private static final String TAG = "CamPreview";

    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private byte[] mVideoSource;
    private Bitmap mBackBuffer;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Context mContext;

    public CamPreview(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
        mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(this);
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
        Log.i(TAG, "@SurfaceCreated: initilization finished");
    } catch (IOException eIOException) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + eIOException.getMessage());
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    }

    private Size findBestResolution(int pWidth, int pHeight) {
    List<Size> lSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    Size lSelectedSize = mCamera.new Size(0, 0);
    for (Size lSize : lSizes) {
        if ((lSize.width <= pWidth)
         && (lSize.height <= pHeight)
         && (lSize.width >= lSelectedSize.width)
         && (lSize.height >= lSelectedSize.height)) {
            lSelectedSize = lSize;
        }
    }
    if ((lSelectedSize.width == 0)
                    || (lSelectedSize.height == 0)) {
        lSelectedSize = lSizes.get(0);
    }
    return lSelectedSize;
    }

    private void createBuffers(String caller, Size prefSize) {
        Camera.Parameters camParams = mCamera.getParameters();

    int previewWidth    = prefSize.width;
    int previewHeight   = prefSize.height;
    mBackBuffer         = Bitmap.createBitmap(previewWidth,
                                            previewHeight,
                                            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Log.i(TAG,"@"+caller+": Piture Width " + Integer.toString(previewWidth));
    Log.i(TAG,"@"+caller+": Piture Height " + Integer.toString(previewHeight));
    Log.i(TAG,"@"+caller+": Piture format " + Integer.toString(ImageFormat.NV21));        

    camParams.setPreviewSize(previewWidth,previewHeight);
    camParams.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);
    mCamera.setParameters(camParams);

    PixelFormat pxlFrmt = new PixelFormat();
    PixelFormat.getPixelFormatInfo(camParams.getPreviewFormat(), pxlFrmt);
    Log.i(TAG,"@"+caller+": Bits per pixel " + Integer.toString(pxlFrmt.bitsPerPixel));
    Log.i(TAG,"@"+caller+": Bytes per pixel " + Integer.toString(pxlFrmt.bytesPerPixel));
    int sz = previewWidth * previewHeight * pxlFrmt.bitsPerPixel/8;        
    mVideoSource = new byte[sz];
    mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mVideoSource);

    Log.i(TAG, "@"+caller+": backbuffer initilization finished");
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        Log.i(TAG, "@SurfaceCreated: preview started");
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
    // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            Log.i(TAG,"No proper holder");
        return;
    }
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.i(TAG,"tried to stop a non-existent preview");
        return;
    }

    createBuffers("surfaceChanged",findBestResolution(w, h));        
    }

    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.i(TAG,"@onPreviewFrame: Invoked");
        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
    Camera.Size camSize = params.getPictureSize();
    int w = camSize.width;
    int h = camSize.height;

    Log.i(TAG,"@onPreviewFrame: Piture Width " + Integer.toString(w));
    Log.i(TAG,"@onPreviewFrame: Piture Height " + Integer.toString(h));
    Log.i(TAG,"@onPreviewFrame: Piture format " + Integer.toString(params.getPictureFormat()));
    PixelFormat pxlFrmt = new PixelFormat();
    PixelFormat.getPixelFormatInfo(params.getPreviewFormat(), pxlFrmt);
    Log.i(TAG,"@onPreviewFrame: Bits per pixel " + Integer.toString(pxlFrmt.bitsPerPixel));
    Log.i(TAG,"@onPreviewFrame: Bytes per pixel " + Integer.toString(pxlFrmt.bytesPerPixel));

    mBackBuffer     = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);        

    Log.i(TAG,"@onPreviewFrame: Back buffer set.");
    invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas pCanvas) {
        super.onDraw(pCanvas);
        Log.i(TAG,"@onDraw: Invoked");
    if (mCamera != null) {
        Log.i(TAG,"@onDraw: Bbefore draw call to canvas");
        pCanvas.drawBitmap(mBackBuffer, 0, 0, mPaint);
        mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mVideoSource);
        Log.i(TAG,"@onDraw: Draw finished");
    }
    }    

    /** Check if this device has a camera */
    private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
        } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
        }
    }

    /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
    private Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        if(checkCameraHardware(mContext)) {
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, "Trying to open the camera");
            c = Camera.open(0);
            Log.i(TAG, "Camera opened successfully.");
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    private void releaseCamera(){
    if (mCamera != null){
        mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
        mCamera = null;
    }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        releaseCamera();
        mVideoSource = null;
        mBackBuffer = null;
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Figured out couple of things after careful reiteration of my reading through the android docs. Apparently preview[Size|Format] is completely different from picture[Size/Format], which i assumed to be one and the same earlier. So, that fixed my rendering issues and crashes due incorrect data format. It also clarifed my confusion of change in camera parameters automatically.

The whole example is working now. However, i am seeing two layers of preview, the one which directly rendered by the camera, and the one i am rendering though onDraw. I am not sure whether i should see both of them or not. Below is the fixed code.

Thank you if anyone who might have spent time on this. Now, i will work on moving the whole onPreviewFrame logic to native code to speed up things! :)

```
public class CamPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PreviewCallback {

    private static final String TAG = "CamPreview";
    private static final int mPreviewWidth = 1280;
    private static final int mPreviewHeight = 720;
    private static final int mFPSXOff = 72;
    private static final int mFPSYOff = 72;
    private static final int mFPSSize = 64;

    private float mTotalTime;
    private float mFrameCount;
    private String mFPS;
    private long  mStart;
    private Context mContext;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private byte[] mVideoSource;
    private Bitmap mBackBuffer;
    private Paint  mPaint; 

    public CamPreview(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mFrameCount = 0;
    mTotalTime = 0;
    mFPS = "0 FPS";
    mStart = 0;
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
    mPaint.setTextSize(mFPSSize);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
        mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(this);
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
    } catch (IOException eIOException) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + eIOException.getMessage());
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    }

    private Size findBestResolution(int pWidth, int pHeight) {
    List<Size> lSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    Size lSelectedSize = mCamera.new Size(0, 0);
    for (Size lSize : lSizes) {
        if ((lSize.width <= pWidth)
         && (lSize.height <= pHeight)
         && (lSize.width >= lSelectedSize.width)
         && (lSize.height >= lSelectedSize.height)) {
            lSelectedSize = lSize;
        }
    }
    if ((lSelectedSize.width == 0)
                    || (lSelectedSize.height == 0)) {
        lSelectedSize = lSizes.get(0);
    }
    return lSelectedSize;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            Log.i(TAG,"No proper holder");
        return;
    }
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(TAG,"tried to stop a non-existent preview");
        return;
    }
    PixelFormat pxlFrmt = new PixelFormat();
        Camera.Parameters camParams = mCamera.getParameters();
    Size previewSize    = findBestResolution(w, h);
    int previewWidth    = previewSize.width;
    int previewHeight   = previewSize.height;
    camParams.setPreviewSize(previewWidth,previewHeight);
    camParams.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);
    mCamera.setParameters(camParams);
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    mBackBuffer         = Bitmap.createBitmap(previewWidth, previewHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    PixelFormat.getPixelFormatInfo(camParams.getPreviewFormat(), pxlFrmt);
    int sz = previewWidth * previewHeight * pxlFrmt.bitsPerPixel/8;        
    mVideoSource = new byte[sz];
    mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mVideoSource);        

    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        Log.i(TAG, "@SurfaceChanged: preview started");
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "@SurfaceChanged:Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    mFrameCount = 0;
    mTotalTime = 0;
    mStart = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    }

    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.i(TAG,"@onPreviewFrame: Invoked");
        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
    Camera.Size camSize = params.getPreviewSize();
    int w = camSize.width;
    int h = camSize.height;
    PixelFormat pxlFrmt = new PixelFormat();
    PixelFormat.getPixelFormatInfo(params.getPreviewFormat(), pxlFrmt);

    try {
        YuvImage yuv = new YuvImage(data,ImageFormat.NV21,w,h,null);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        yuv.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0,0,w,h), 100, baos);
        byte[] jpgData = baos.toByteArray();
        mBackBuffer = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpgData, 0, jpgData.length);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ;
    }
    Log.i(TAG,"@onPreviewFrame: Backbuffer set.");
    postInvalidate();
    mFrameCount++;
    long end = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    mTotalTime += (end-mStart);
    mStart = end;
    mFPS = Float.toString((1000*mFrameCount/mTotalTime))+" fps";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas pCanvas) {
        Log.i(TAG,"@onDraw: Invoked");
    if (mCamera != null) {
        if(mBackBuffer==null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Back buffer is null :((((((( ");
        } else {
            pCanvas.drawBitmap(mBackBuffer, 0, 0, null);
            pCanvas.drawText(mFPS, mFPSXOff, mFPSYOff, mPaint);
            mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mVideoSource);
        }
    }
    }    

    private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
        return true;
        } else {
        return false;
        }
    }

    private Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        if(checkCameraHardware(mContext)) {
            try {
            c = Camera.open(0);
            Log.i(TAG, "Camera opened successfully");
            Camera.Parameters params = c.getParameters();
            params.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);
            params.setPreviewSize(mPreviewWidth, mPreviewHeight);
            c.setParameters(params);
            Log.i(TAG, "NV21 format set to camera with resolution 1280x720");
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    private void releaseCamera(){
    if (mCamera != null){
        mCamera.release();
        Log.i(TAG,"@releaseCamera:");
        mCamera = null;
    }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        releaseCamera();
        mVideoSource = null;
        mBackBuffer = null;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing the decoding in native method instead of using YuvImage doubled the FPS.